# I am getting following error when I run npm install -g ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am getting following errors when I run npm install -g ionic :-

```
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.1.9: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead!
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.1.0: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: They're all warnings it seems

Comment: Yes they are warnings.  But perhaps illuminating what the warnings mean would be handy?  Why, when installing a package, does npm give warnings about other packages?  It also requests the user to "Please update", "Upgrade", or "use".  Such warnings might lead a person to try to reinstall graceful-fs 20 times.  So the real question is:  "Can somebody explain this to me?"